# stream mp3 to the browser instead of saving the data as a file

Tags: php, streaming, readfile

I am using the following php class to convert text to speech: http://www.masnun.me/2009/12/14/googles-text-to-speech-api-a-php-wrapper-class.html

its using google's API, and right now the code saves the file locally however I want it to stream the file to user's browser by force. this is what I came up with:

```
function saveToFile($filename) {
    $filename = trim($filename);
    if(!empty($filename)) {
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header('Content-length: ' . filesize($this->mp3data));
            header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename);
            header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
            readfile($this->mp3data);
    } else { return false; }
}
```

but the produced file is 0kb empty mp3 file. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `$this->mp3data` empty? What's in the `Content-length` header?

Comment: $this->mp3data is what you get back from google's api, its an mp3 file.

Comment: NOTE: `$this->mp3data` holds the content of the file, not a url to the file. now how can I stream this to the users as an mp3 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `readfile` actually echo to the browser? If it's just returning something it won't work how you expect:

```
echo readfile($this->mp3data);
```

I also understand that readfile works with a path, if that is the case, just try:

```
echo $this->mp3data;
```

Comment: [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is a built in php function. It outputs to the buffer and returns an int.

Answer (score 2):

`readfile()` accepts a filename as parameter, not the content of a file.
Try replacing the readfile line with this:

```
echo $this->mp3data;
```